# Objective-C (copy) property: copy for setters or for getters?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, copy

As I understand from documentation, (copy) used for setters only. So, the setting method would be (pseudo-code):

```
prop = [_prop copy];
```

And seems that getter looks like:

```
return prop;
```

Am I right ?

Comment: How are you declaring your property?

Comment: @property (readonly) NSString *str;

Comment: Any particular reason why you would want to use a copy over a retain?

Comment: To separate class from mutable nature of the passed property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the implementation is similar to

```
prop = [_prop copy];
```

plus a few more lines.
It is primarily used when you set a mutable parameter, which you don't want to be changed.